# inheritance in Cython (short sample code)

Tags: python, inheritance, cython

In the following sample code, a cython class (**Q**) is imported. Two instances of Q are created (**q1** and **q2**). I'd like to alter a variable inside q1 and have it affect the same variable inside q2.

Thank you very much for your time and any related information on scope or inheritance in Cython!

**tc1.pyx:**

```
cimport cython

cdef class Q:
    cdef public double q

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.q = 0

    def addone(self):
        self.q += 1

    property gsd:  # get set return
        def __get__(self):
            return self.q
        def __set__(self, value):
            pass
        def __del__(self):
            pass
```

**.py file:**

```
from tc1 import Q

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q1 = Q()
    q2 = Q()

    print 'q1: ', q1.gsd, 'q2: ', q2.gsd  # >> 0 and 0

    q1.addone()

    print 'q1: ', q1.gsd, 'q2: ', q2.gsd  # >> 1 and 0 (1 and 1 desired)
```

Comment: Thats not "inheritance". q1 and q2 are 'siblings' with independent attributes. Can you replace Q, q1 and q2 with names describing them so we can help?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I feel foolish, but what is it that I'm looking for? I'd like a certain variable defined in a class to be shared between all instances (children?) of the class

Comment: Well, that really depends on what you are trying to do. What exactly is `Q` meant to represent?

Comment: Your answer nailed it! But I can't figure out how to alter it into Cython.

Comment: Seems like my answer may not be possible in Cython. Perhaps, if you could explain what `Q` *actually* represents an alternate solution might be possible? Why do all objects of type `Q` need to share an attribute? Are they a collection?

Comment: I'm just trying to get an understanding of what Cython can do-- I'm still planning how I'm going to write my program, how to organize scope. I thought this scenario was common, so I assumed it to exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython classes compile to C, where the class members are just values in a struct; so there's no notion of static variables for cdef classes.

You can simply declare a global pointer that Q references, however:

```
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef public double* global_q = <double*>malloc(sizeof(double))
global_q[0] = 0
def call_at_end():
    free(global_q)

cdef class Q:
    cdef double* q

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.q = global_q

    def addone(self):
        self.q[0] += 1

    property gsd:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.q[0]
        def __set__(self, double value):
            self.q[0] = value
```

Now your main function will work as expected. I added the function call_at_end to free the memory just to show how you would do it, but in this case you would never free the memory for as long as you could make an instance of Q.

Comment: Could you explain the double* notation? I don't understand the line: global_q[0] = 0. Is that a place in memory as opposed to the usual location in an array? (thank you!)

Comment: Sure! So a double* is a pointer to a double. Arrays in C are allocated as blocks of memory, where you have a pointer to the first bit of that memory. If you want a pointer to just one double, you just need to allocate enough memory to fit that one double (That's why I "malloc" (memory allocate) a sizeof(double)). When you use global_q[0], you're basically saying "give me the first double that global_q points to".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you do it in Cython, but here is an attempt that solves it in regular Python. I'd presume if you change the propery code to use Cython decorators it should work fine.

First you need a [class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), for example `_bar`, then we adjust the property getter and setter methods to alter this, instead of an instance variable. The code below should illustrate this and you can [verify it works on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/ZcQzJd):

```
class Foo(object):
    _bar = 0

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return Foo._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
       Foo._bar = value

    @bar.deleter
    def bar(self):
        pass

a = Foo()
b = Foo()

print a.bar
print b.bar

a.bar += 1

print a.bar
print b.bar
```

This outputs the below as desired:

```
0
0
1
1
```

Comment: I've been trying this, but it throws an error in Cython: 

tc1.pyx:4:23: Cannot assign default value to fields in cdef classes, structs or unions
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: You could try and split the definition and assignment on to two lines. However it seems that Cython rejects defaults for class variables.

Comment: Yep, splitting it up still throws the error. Maybe I should ask this: Does this behaviour exist in C++ as well? If so this is perfectly reasonable.